# Azure DevOps Pipeline - condition expression with pipeline variable

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

I need to make my stages in DevOps YAML pipeline dependent or not based on **pipeline variable** (not variable defined in the YAML).

I tried something like this:

```
- stage: 'test'
  ${{ if eq(variables.dependent_stages, 'true') }}:
    dependsOn: [dev]
  ${{ elseif eq(variables.dependent_stages, 'false') }}:
    dependsOn: []
  jobs:
  - deployment: approve
    environment: TEST
```

However it always takes it as "true" as it is default value of the variable.

How to make it reflect actual value of the pipeline variable?

Comment: If you use `${{ ` then it will be evaluated very early, when the pipeline is compiled. It will not change at runtime when the variable might have changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not the solution I hoped for, but solved with parameters:

```
parameters:
- name: dependent_stages
  displayName: Should environments depend on each other?
  type: string
  default: No
  values:
  - No
  - Yes

...

- stage: 'test'
  ${{ if eq(parameters.dependent_stages, 'Yes') }}:
    dependsOn: [dev]
  ${{ elseif eq(parameters.dependent_stages, 'No') }}:
    dependsOn: []
```